# link an Array Controller to an Array in XCode via outlets

Tags: cocoa, arrays, interface-builder, linker

I'm trying to find a way to link an array controller to an Array.
I know via an outlet I can fill textfields and even tableviews in the .xib file made with Interface Builder.

I was hoping it would be possible to have one easy outlet (NSArray) and put it into an Array Controller. In turn, a table will link its contentfield to the stuff in the Array. Is this possible or am I just thinking too much non-cocoa?

Right now I have an Object Reference in Interface builder which already passes through a pair of fields and some action handers to buttons. If I try to link the Array Controller to the outlet 'FilesArray' I can only link it to the Object itself, not its outlets.

I'm only a beginner so I don't see why this wouldn't be possible?

thanks!

Comment: I've got it setup as mentioned by Peter Hosey.
However, the table consists out of six columns. How do I make the first column (called artist and with no binding yet) show the field... Should I have arrays inside the main array that holds the collection. Apple doesn't cover this well for beginners

Comment: Nested arrays do *not* work with Bindings. You need one array containing one model object per row. The columns, then, are properties of the model objects (e.g., you'd bind the artist column to the array controller's arrangedObjects, model key path “artist”).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to go to the Bindings Pane in the Interface builder inspector and under the "Controller Content" for a NSArrayController you need to bind to the array you want. Then you can just bind the NSTableColumn to the NSArray Controller.

See
[With and Without Bindings](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/WithAndWithoutBindings/index.html) for an example of using NSArrayController.

Also CocoaDev gives some more precise instructions on using NSArrayController and using it with TableViews http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSArrayController

Comment: 404 on both links. :(

Comment: To use the add: selector of the binding I know I need to add the class name in the attributes inspector of the Array controller (in IB)., but do you know what I should write if my Xcode project is 2 words (e.g. "My Project")? Adding the Class name as: My-Project.MyClass doesn't seem to find the class :(

Answer (score 2):

You don't use an outlet for this. Instead, you go the other way, and bind the array controller to a property of your object.

1. Delete the `IBOutlet` keyword.
2. In the header, declare the instance variable as an `NSMutableArray`.
3. In the implementation, create the array in `init` and release it in `dealloc`.
4. In the header, declare a property for the array. Make sure to declare it with the copy attribute.
5. In the implementation, synthesize accessors for the property.
6. In IB, set the array controller's Content Array binding. Bind it to the object that has your array property. Set the model key path to the name of the property you created in Xcode.
7. In your implementation, *always* use accessors to mutate the property (e.g., to add or remove objects).